# Reason why dot notation isn't used for time derivatives in Maxwell's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, time, notation, differentiation, maxwell-equations

Maxwell's equations seem to be usually written:

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &= \rho/\epsilon_0,\\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0,\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t},\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} &= \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t},
\end{align}

as opposed to

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &= \rho/\epsilon_0,\\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0,\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= -\dot{\mathbf{B}},\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} &= \mu_0 \mathbf{J} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\dot{\mathbf{E}} \, .
\end{align}

Is there any particular reason the more concise dot notation isn't used?

Comment: In my experience the dot notation in almost only used in Newtonian physics (including analytic Newtonian physics).

Comment: Could it be a will to insist on the fact that we have a *partial* differential here ? I believe the dot notation is used more widely as $\frac{d}{dt}$ than  $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Newton's notation is not used for partial derivatives.  Besides, using the standard notation, helps realising that time and Space differentiation act as a unified 4D operator  (exterior derivative) when using exterior form notation

Answer (score 2):

The dot notation typically refers to a total time derivative. In field theory partial & total time derivatives of the field are often the same, and the dot notation can sometimes be seen in the field theory literature as a convenient short-hand.
An important exception is the [material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative) in fluid dynamics.
Similar ambiguities arise e.g. for a point particle ${\bf r}(t)$ in an EM background, say an electric potential $\phi$, where the total and partial time derivative differ by a transport term
$$\frac{d\phi({\bf r}(t),t)}{dt}
~=~\frac{\partial\phi({\bf r}(t),t)}{\partial t} + \dot{\bf r}(t)\cdot 
\nabla \phi({\bf r}(t),t). $$